# Sorting by Value in a python dictionary where value is a tuple

Tags: python, sorting

I'm using this line and all works well until I get a three digit number, this then gets sorted after a two digit number. Where I want the order in reverse order.

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k), reverse=True)[:30]:
```

printing out mydict then gives:-

```
carrots (68.5,5) 
pears (53.5,5)   
potatoes (39.5,5) 
tomatoes (34.0,5.0)
apples (29.0,5.0)
cabbage (28.5,5)
cheese  (27.5,5)
chrisps(23.0,2.5)
cakes  (16.0,3)
goatscheese  (144.0,5.0)  
Pizza (12.0,4.0)
```

So need the sort on three digit number 144 to then be above two digit 68, looks like the sort is only occurring on the first two digits, by the placing in the sort. I'm also not interested in sorting the key at all only the first number in the Tuple. thanks for any help on this and sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: It looks like your "numbers" are actually strings. Convert them to `float`.

Comment: *How* are you printing `mydict` out?

Comment: I'm just printing the following into a html format:-

Comment: print "<H3> %s: ......... %s  </H3>" % (key, value)

Comment: the print is part of the for loop

Comment: Can you try `for key, value in sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (float(v),k), reverse=True)[:30]:` ?

Comment: Thanks tobias, yep needed to convert string to a float.

Comment: I had to also do some string length checks to make sure the string was valid  number wise as a string to turn to a float :-

Comment: for line in f:
        str= line.replace(', ',',')
        (key,val) = str.split()
        if len(val) == 11:
                val=float(val[1:5]) , float(val[7:9])
        if len(val) == 10:
                val=float(val[1:4]) , float(val[6:8])
        if len(val) == 9:
                val=float(val[1:3]) , float(val[5:7])
        if len(val) == 8:
                val=float(val[1:2]) , float(val[4:6])

        print val
        
        mydict[(key)] =val

Comment: I'm sure there's more an elegant pythonic way of doing this and a shorter way, but it works.

Comment: basically turning a string that looked like a tuple into a tuple with numbers in using float, then the sorted line worked.